# Rails Premailer image reference on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, premailer

I am using premailer, and on my local machine I get links like this in the mail notes:

```
file://localhost/assets/header_logo.png
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/header_logo.png
```

How do I configure premailer so that the url is correct while in development?

I tried adding

```
Premailer::Rails.config.merge!(base_url: "http://localhost:3000")
```

to my development config file,  but the server barfs saying there is no method Premailer::Rails.config.

I also did this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I was still using the premailer-rails3 gem, but reading the premailer-rails doc.  Just updating the gem to premailer-rails fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the archives... you can also put this into say config/initializers/premailer.rb and it will pick up whatever you've set for ActionMailer...

```
Premailer::Rails.config.merge!(
  :base_url => "http://#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}"
)
```